# Transaction configure failed in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

update:

I found that I inject class A into class C which extends an external class, 
and that class didn't managed by spring, like this:

```
public class C extends ExternalClass {    
    @AutoWired
    private A a;
    //doSomething...    
}
```

That should be the main cause of transaction failure.

Another question: is there any way to make spring manage transaction of class A which has injected into anothor class that isn't handled by spring?

---

I'm building a project with Spring Boot and Mybatis.

I have a problem that one of service class cannot a create transactional connection and won't perform a roll back.

I found that if I removed injection of A Class in B Class, like this:

```
class A{
    //@Autowired
    //private B b;
    // b is not used in this class
    @Autowired
    private ADao dao;
}

class B{
    @Autowired 
    private BDao dao;

    //Transaction of this method failed
    //session didn't roll back
     public void (){
          dao.insert(new Entity ());
          //Exception here
     }
}
```

The connection created by class B would be transactional. Both of two class are in the same package, but if I add that injection, the transaction would fail. What made me much confused is that class B can inject into other class, and transaction would work well too.

Here is the log:

```
2018-01-05 21:30:33.861 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       97 : Creating a new SqlSession
2018-01-05 21:30:33.866 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       148 : SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3aeb5ca8] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
2018-01-05 21:30:33.888 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      110 : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2018-01-05 21:30:33.888 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          142 : Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true]
2018-01-05 21:30:33.905 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction         87 : JDBC Connection [org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLConnection@2bad8689] will not be managed by Spring
2018-01-05 21:30:33.908 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] p.c.z.admin.dao.UserDao.insertSelective  159 : ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO sys_user ( id,username ) VALUES( ?,? ) 
2018-01-05 21:30:33.916 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] p.c.z.admin.dao.UserDao.insertSelective  159 : ==> Parameters: null, test(String)
2018-01-05 21:30:33.929 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] p.c.z.admin.dao.UserDao.insertSelective  159 : <==    Updates: 1
2018-01-05 21:30:33.932 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] p.c.z.a.d.U.insertSelective!selectKey    159 : ==>  Executing: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() 
2018-01-05 21:30:33.940 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] p.c.z.a.d.U.insertSelective!selectKey    159 : <==      Total: 1
2018-01-05 21:30:33.942 DEBUG 10346 --- [http-nio-8099-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       191 : Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3aeb5ca8]
```

I've tried 3 ways to config transaction:

with java config:

```
@Bean(name = "transactionInterceptor")
public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
    transactionInterceptor.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    Properties transactionAttributes = new Properties();
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("insert*","PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Throwable");
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("update*","PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Throwable");
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("delete*","PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Throwable");
    transactionAttributes.setProperty("select*","PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Throwable,readOnly");
    transactionInterceptor.setTransactionAttributes(transactionAttributes);
    return transactionInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator transactionAutoProxy() {
    BeanNameAutoProxyCreator transactionAutoProxy = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
    transactionAutoProxy.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    transactionAutoProxy.setBeanNames("*ServiceImpl");
    transactionAutoProxy.setInterceptorNames("transactionInterceptor");
    return transactionAutoProxy;
}
```

and with xml：

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="del*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="services"
                  expression="execution(* root.*.service.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="services" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
</aop:config>
```

and with @Transactional.
However none of them worked.

Comment: You don't need transaction configuration, it is configured out-of-the-box... You only need to add `@Transactional`. If there is something wrong post the exception/stacktrace you get.

Comment: i tried that, but didn't work.

Comment: Then your setup is borked somewhere (or the code you posted here doesn't reflect the actual code). `@Transactional` is all you need. Also what makes you think the transaction failed? As stated if there is an exception etc. add it to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if that injection is the main cause of failure. I think it should cause by  configuration. Maybe I should check my project again.

Comment: I made some exception in some classes, and only one class didn't roll back.

Comment: That still doesn't mean it doesn't work... If those are 2 separate transactions it works as designed, if the overall method was `@Transactional` it should be a single transaction but if you call 2 `@Transactional` methods from a non-transactional method it will be 2 separate transactions.

Comment: I did inject B class into A, but I didn't use that. All mehtod failed are only in class B. I'll edit my question to explain that.

Comment: There is still some crucial information missing, what you posted here should work. So there must be something special about `A` that you aren't explaining/telling here.

Comment: I thought I found the reason for that failure, but I wonder if there is any way to inject  a class into external classes without break beans management?

Comment: As stated it shouldn't matter where you inject the dependency it should just work. Unless it isn't a spring managed bean but in that case injection would be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you inject a class into another one which is not a spring managed bean, then the spring transaction management will failed.
So while having a transaction failure, go check if there is a wrong dependency injection.